# Polling overall diagnostics state

Tags: ros, diagnostic-aggregator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you find the overall diagnostics state from the diagnostics aggregator?

My diagnostics are running and viewable in RQT monitor, and now I'd like to make a simple rospy node that sets a status LED to red if there's an error, and green otherwise.

[From the docs](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostic_aggregator), I see there's a `/diagnostics_toplevel_state` topic, which I intuit should contain this info, but when I echo it, all I see is:

```
level: 2
name: toplevel_state
message: ''
hardware_id: ''
values: []
```

do all blank values mean everything is ok, or am I misinterpreting this? Is there a better way to poll the diagnostics aggregator?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251971/polling-overall-diagnostics-state/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-01-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `/diagnostics_toplevel_state` is the correct way to get a state summary from the diagnostic aggregator.

The `level` field indicates the state and is set from the OK, WARN, ERROR or STALE enum values defined in the [DiagnosticStatus message](http://docs.ros.org/api/diagnostic_msgs/html/msg/DiagnosticStatus.html).

In this case, `level: 2` corresponds to `ERROR`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1